# Bash find | while read - few variables

Tags: bash, while-loop, find

Is there a way to save output of find (few arguments) to few variables? What I need to do is take output of find and give it as input to while and use read as well. I can't use test with -r -w or -x (it's an academic exercise).

Something like this:

```
find $1 -writable -printf "%f %p\n" , -readable -printf "%f %p\n" , -executable -printf "%f %p\n" | while read var1 var2 var3
do

    echo $var1
    echo $var2
    echo $var3

done
```

In var1 I want to have only writable files, var2 readable, var3 executable.
Instead of that it's all in var1.

Comment: Why not go the easy way with three different `find` commands? Why combine three data streams just to pick them apart?

Comment: I can't use more then one find in exercise. Anyway, I got the answer. – read takes one line of whatever is in input and works with that, so when find is printing files with new line character it goes everytime to only one variable. Instead of using read var1 var2 var3 right after while I should've used read var1 after while and read var2, read var3 within the loop. So basically use more than just one read if input is printed with new lines.

Answer (score 1):

Do not understand your exercise, but maybe something like could usable as for start

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    [[ -w "$file" ]] && f_wrt+=("$file")
    [[ -r "$file" ]] && f_rdr+=("$file")
    [[ -x "$file" ]] && f_exe+=("$file")
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)

printf "writeable  : %s\n" "${f_wrt[@]}"
printf "readable   : %s\n" "${f_rdr[@]}"
printf "executable : %s\n" "${f_exe[@]}"
```